# Accessing an object not working with a variable

Tags: javascript, html, variables

This seems simple but I'm banging against a wall. My code gets weights, accesses an object array to get a value then calculates a result using that value * weight. But accessing the object doesn't work with a variable.

```
 function calc(){
var gender;
if(document.getElementById("male").checked){
    gender = "mensList";
} else if (document.getElementById("female").checked){
    gender = "womensList";
} else {
    alert("Please select a gender");
    return false;
}
var kg = parseInt(document.getElementById("bwKg").value);
var grams = parseFloat(document.getElementById("bwGrams").value);
var bw = parseFloat(kg + grams);
var lifted = parseFloat(document.getElementById("liftWeight").value);

var theValue = womensList[bw]; // This works
var theValue = mensList[bw];   // This also works
var theValue = gender[bw];     // This doesn't work
var theValue = gender + "[\"" + bw + "\"]" // Nor this

var result = theValue * lifted;
document.getElementById("result").textContent = result;
 }

 var womensList = {
  40.0: "1.4936",
  40.1: "1.4915",
  40.2: "1.4894",
  40.3: "1.4872",
  40.4: "1.4851",
  // ......... etc
  150.7: "0.7691",
  150.8: "0.7691",
 150.9: "0.7691"
};

var mensList = {
  40.0: "1.3354",
  40.1: "1.3311",
  40.2: "1.3268",
  40.3: "1.3225",
  40.9: "1.2975",
  // ......... etc
  205.7: "0.5318",
  205.8: "0.5318",
  205.9: "0.5318"
 };
```

Comment: You are setting `gender` to a string not an object.

Comment: So...... eval(gender)[bw]; Yeah, that works. Thanks.

Comment: Probably not. Why are you assigning a string to gender rather than the object directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are setting a `gender` to `string` not variable.

```
if(document.getElementById("male").checked){
    gender = "mensList";
} else if (document.getElementById("female").checked){
    gender = "womensList";
}
```

Should be

```
if(document.getElementById("male").checked){
    gender = mensList;
} else if (document.getElementById("female").checked){
    gender = womensList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your problem :

```
if(document.getElementById("male").checked){
    gender = "mensList";                         //gender now contains a string only..
} else if
```

Since gender contains a mere string, this will not work:

```
var theValue = gender[bw];     // This doesn't work
```

What you should be doing instead is :

```
if(document.getElementById("male").checked){
    gender = mensList;                         //now gender contains an array provided mensList is defined beforehand ..
}
```